# Group together Jasmine's it specs into a single test run

Tags: jasmine

I have the following situation:

```
describe('Base test suite', function () {
    beforeEach(function (done) {
        // an initialization routine with done as the callback
        veryLongInitialization(done);
    });

    it('description of first spec', function (done) {
        // first expectations

        done();
    });

    describe('nested suite that builds upon the base test suite', function () {
        beforeEach(function (done) {
            secondVeryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        it('description of second spec', function (done) {
            // second expectations
        });
    });

    describe('second nested suite that builds upon the base test suite', function () {
        beforeEach(function (done) {
            thirdVeryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        it('description of third spec', function (done) {
            // third expectations
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, we have some nested test suites. It's very important that the outer `beforeEach` is called before the inner one.

- When the outer expectations are executed (first spec), `veryLongInitialization` must have been completed.
- For the second spec (first nested spec), it's required that `veryLongInitialization` and `secondVeryLongInitialization` have been executed sequentially, and completed successfully.
- Likewise, for the third spec (second nested spec), it's required that `veryLongInitialization` and `thirdVeryLongInitialization` have been executed sequentially, and completed successfully.

This works very nice so far.

**However,** there are many expectations in the first spec, so it's basically impossible to write a short description for it.

So we thought about splitting the first spec into several specs with only a few expectations per spec. This would make it easy to write meaningful, short spec descriptions.

**However,** this slows down the complete test execution, since `veryLongInitialization` has to be executed for each spec.

So we thought about putting `veryLongInitialization` into a `beforeAll` block instead of `beforeEach`. This would execute `veryLongInitialization` only once, and then run all the specs, thereby speeding up overall test execution.

**However,** this means that `veryLongInitialization` would run only once at all. This means that the third spec would be run after the sequence

```
veryLongInitialization()
secondVeryLongInitialization()
thirdVeryLongInitialization()
```

which is incorrect. `secondVeryLongInitialization` should not have run before the third specs.

I hope you see our dilemma. **Is there a better approach for this scenario?**

What we would like to see is some way of grouping the specs together, for example:

```
it('should do this', function () {
    ...
}).and('should do that', function () {
    ...
}).and('should also behave like this', function () {
    ...
}).and('should also behave like that', function () {
    ...
});
```

These specs would be run in a single test run, with only one `beforeEach` for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work: combine first step specs into a separate `describe` and run `veryLongInitialization` before all of them. After that run `veryLongInitialization` before all in the second `describe` and `secondVeryLongInitialization` before each. The same for  the third step. This way you'll have to run `veryLongInitialization` three times, but it is actually what a particular suite requires according to your description. If you are worried about code duplication for `veryLongInitialization` it can be moved to a separate function and called multiple times when needed.

```
describe('Base test suite', function () {

    // for multiple time usage
    var veryLongInitialization = function (done) {
        done();
    };

    describe('first', function () {

        beforeAll(function (done) {
            veryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        // ...
    });

    describe('second', function () {

        beforeAll(function (done) {
            veryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            secondVeryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        // ...
    });

    describe('third', function () {

        beforeAll(function (done) {
            veryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            thirdVeryLongInitialization(done);
        });

        // ...
    });

});
```

Comment: You're right, that's most likely the best solution. Too bad that this makes the nested test suites somewhat less usable.